# Anaconda export Environment file

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

How can I make anaconda environment file which could be use on other computers?

I exported my anaconda python environment to YML using `conda env export > environment.yml`. The exported `environment.yml` contains this line `prefix: /home/superdev/miniconda3/envs/juicyenv` which maps to my anaconda's location which will be different on other's pcs.

Comment: I was just doing some testing, and thought I found the prefix is ignored... not sure why it is in the env export. You should be able to do

    `conda env create -f environment.yml`

Just as an aside, in my experience this is not going to work across platforms, because conda env will list many dependencies such as ` vs2015_runtime` if you are on Windows. But of course that is not available on linux.

Comment: Note that there are [good instructions for this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms) in the docs now; I'm guessing this section didn't exist when these answers were originally written.

Comment: @AlexGRice: This is not fully true anymore, as there is the [--from-history](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) flag for sharing cross-platform which only adds the packages that have been added by the user (nevertheless these could also be platform dependent).

Answer (score 377, accepted):

I can't find anything in the `conda` specs which allows you to export an environment file without the `prefix: ...` line. However, like [Alex pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274007/anaconda-export-environment-file/41274348#comment69750196_41274007) in the comments, conda doesn't seem to care about the prefix line when creating an environment from the file.

With that in mind, if you want the other user to have no knowledge of your default install path, you can remove the prefix line with `grep` before writing to `environment.yml`.

```
conda env export | grep -v "^prefix: " > environment.yml
```

Either way, the other user then runs:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

and the environment will get installed in their default conda environment path.

If you want to specify a different install path than the default for your system (not related to 'prefix' in the environment.yml), just use the `-p` flag followed by the required path.

```
conda env create -f environment.yml -p /home/user/anaconda3/envs/env_name
```

Note that Conda recommends creating the `environment.yml` by hand, which is especially important if you are wanting to share your environment across platforms (Windows/Linux/Mac). In this case, you can just leave out the `prefix` line.

Comment: ...eggcellent! 

Comment: I'm guessing the `prefix` helps create new environments faster when used on the same machine, but I don't have much evidence for this claim. I once ran without the `prefix` and it had to download some extra packages that it didn't need to do before. And yet, that only happened once, so maybe after that they were cached on a system level(?) So, not needed for sharing, but maybe desirable when just using it for yourself.

Answer (score 93):

The easiest way to save the packages from an environment to be installed in another computer is:

```
$ conda list -e > req.txt
```

then you can install the environment using

```
$ conda create -n <environment-name> --file req.txt
```

if you use `pip`, please use the following commands: reference https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

```
$ env1/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ env2/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't seem to work with pip installed packages, however.

Comment: thank you I just updated based on the given reference

Comment: I've used both Anaconda Navigator and pip (from within the environment) to install things.  What would you recommend I use?  Both commands?

Comment: I think it is better to use the conda command in Anaconda environment, you can also use pip if it is needed

Comment: is this method better than installing from *.yml? What are the advantages of this method?

Comment: The advantage would only be that this is cross-compatible with users who want to use `pip` instead of `conda`.

Answer (score 87):

- Linux or Mac

> conda env export --no-builds | grep -v "prefix" > environment.yml

- Windows

> conda env export --no-builds | findstr -v "prefix" > environment.yml

---

Rationale: By default, `conda env export` includes the build information:

```bash
$ conda env export
...
dependencies:
  - backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - boto=2.49.0=py_0
...
```

You can instead export your environment without build info:

```bash
$ conda env export --no-builds
...
dependencies:
  - backcall=0.1.0
  - blas=1.0
  - boto=2.49.0
...
```

Which unties the environment from the Python version and OS.

Comment: I agree that this is a good answer, but consider adding some details on why excluding build info is useful for transferring envs across platforms.

Comment: Ended up using this, but great idea @merv. Did just that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not always work when installing exporting and re-installing on different OS.

Answer (score 23):

First activate your Conda environment (Below, myenv is the supposed name of the environment).

```
conda activate myenv
```

Then you just need to run this command

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Note that you could replace environment.yml with any other filename of your choice.

Answer (score 8):

1. First activate your conda environment (the one u want to export/backup)

```
conda activate myEnv
```

2. Export all packages to a file (myEnvBkp.txt)

```
conda list --explicit > myEnvBkp.txt
```

3. Restore/import the environment:

```
conda create --name myEnvRestored --file myEnvBkp.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

I find exporting the packages in string format only is more portable than exporting the whole `conda` environment. As the previous answer already suggested:

```
$ conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

However, this `requirements.txt` contains build numbers which are not portable between operating systems, e.g. between `Mac` and `Ubuntu`. In `conda env export` we have the option `--no-builds` but not with `conda list -e`, so we can remove the build number by issuing the following command:

```
$ sed -i -E "s/^(.*\=.*)(\=.*)/\1/" requirements.txt
```

And recreate the environment on another computer:

```
conda create -n recreated_env --file requirements.txt
```

Comment: `sed` command worked pretty nice.  I had to delete a patch version.  So `major.minor.patch` to `major.minor` and it worked.   Turns out, the lower patch number had been dropped by the main repos.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows Users

1. Open CMD
2. Conda Activate SpidersEnv
3. conda env export > SpidersEnv.yml
   [image]
   Then browse the user folder and search for SpidersEnv.yml
   [image]

this is also another way to [backup](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/manage-environments/#backing-up-an-environment) (export) your environment

Answer (score 2):

For me the procedure given by Conda worked:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment

But only if executed in an anaconda prompt/ console.

VSCode terminal only generated a yml-file with a path to my environment, but no explicit list of packages in the dependencies.

Comment: In particular, it seems the desired steps are in the sub-section [Exporting an environment file across platforms](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms). I'm guessing this doc didn't exist until recently. Although, with the `--from-history` option, `pip` packages are not included. So if you have some of those you should add them manually (could be copied from the full export).

Answer (score 1):

*I use Linux, so the following answer is for linux only*

After collecting all the commands I use the following one

`conda env export --no-builds | grep -v "^prefix: " > environment.yml`

Export without the build information and then remove the "prefix" from the environment yml file.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for my case(from x86 to arch64) so far:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4339#issuecomment-311804578

`conda env export | cut -f 1 -d '=' | grep -v "prefix" > environment.yml`

In addition, if you are moving between machine architectures(x86_64 > arch64)
you need to adjust some incompatible packages manually. For example Intel specific mkl*,ld_impl_linux-64...

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and you want short, editable environment variables, use the `--from-history` option like so:
(I also use [micromamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/micromamba-installation.html) in stead of bloated, slow (ana)conda, your resulting file may differ)

```bash
conda create -n jupyter jupyter
conda activate jupyter
conda env export # shows huge list of dependencies
conda env export --from-history # shows only jupyter
conda env export --from-history > environment.yml
```

Will create `environment.yml` as:

```yaml
name: jupyter
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
- jupyter
```

Note that this does not include pip-installed packages. Normally those should be few and only installed after any conda-installed packages. I add them manually after.