# Conda base environment in default form

Tags: virtualenv, conda, miniconda

How can I uninstall all the packages installed later (by me) by pip and conda and put the base environment in the default(when conda/miniconda installed) form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda: remove all installed packages from base/root environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830307/conda-remove-all-installed-packages-from-base-root-environment) Note that a full reversion to 0 can be unstable if the environment is too old (e.g., Anaconda Cloud may have removed some packages). Also, see this answer for cleaning up pip installed packages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682565/570918

Comment: Thanks. It partially solved the problem.