# If I remove a conda environment will it automatically remove all packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I would think it's obvious that it should uninstall all packages when removing an environment, since how would they be accessed otherwise, but I haven't seen documentation saying so, so I'm checking here if all packages need to be removed first.

Comment: you could just create a sample env and then delete it to see what happens

Comment: I think it depends on your OS, you may have to manually delete packages yourself, according to [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/)

Comment: I use windows 10

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's be more specific and remove the env **foo** located at `anaconda3/envs/foo` with

```bash
conda env remove -n foo
```

This usually deletes everything under `anaconda3/envs/foo`.

**PyPI packages may stick around**. If you previously used `pip install` in the environment, it can occasionally leave some residual things behind. If that's the case, you'll need to delete the `anaconda3/envs/foo` folder manually after `conda env remove`. Or you could try to `pip uninstall` any PyPI packages first<sup>**1**</sup>, to get a clean `conda env remove` result.

**Conda also caches all packages**, independent of whether or not they are currently in use. This would be under `anaconda3/pkgs` (usually). To additionally delete the packages no longer in use, one can use

```bash
conda clean -tp  # delete tarballs and unused packages
```

---

<sub>**1:** There is a command to programmatically remove all PyPI-installed packages from Conda environments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682565/570918).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The conda environment will be deleted. Sometimes some packages stay behind, although they are not bound to any environment. You can delete these under
`<your anaconda folder> -> envs -> <the env you deleted>`.