# conda: remove all installed packages from base?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using python v3.9 and anaconda on windows and I installed a bunch of packages in my base conda environment where now I am facing problems from there being conflicts between packages, not allowing me to install more packages that I require for my project. I am trying to reset my whole conda base environment and create new environments for my projects(which I should have done in the first place)

I know that there is a similar post already created :
[conda: remove all installed packages from base/root environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830307/conda-remove-all-installed-packages-from-base-root-environment) but I have tried them and I am still unsuccessful

I have tried reverting back my environment to original state before installing any additional packages but listing my revisions show that I am currently still in revision 0 so I am unable to do so.

I tried removing all installed packages from my environment using awk but I am unable to use awk as installing awk caused the same errors. I tried installing mamba which I have heard helps in resolving conflicts in packages but am again unable to install it due to the same conflicts.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
```

I have also tried deleting everything and uninstalling before reinstalling anaconda but everytime I reinstalled it, it has the same base with all the packages inside.

How do I uninstall the packages in the base environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$conda clean --all
by using this command you can remove old packages. and then delete all environment and reset the

Comment: Did you mean reset the conda? If so, could you please clarify?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: vlokhande39's computer died while writing this answer