# conda remove package extremely slow, not working at all

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, data-science, conda

A couple days back I started getting these weird errors when working on my jupyter notebook.  I realized that the [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/) package I had installed an hour ago required WSL and was likely to be the cause of these issues.

Thus, I've been trying to remove this package, at least for now.  But unfortunately, after an entire weekend I am still right where I started.

When using the command "conda remove nbdev", I get the following response:

```
(base) C:\Users\Ben>conda remove nbdev
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
```

"solving environment" seemingly never ends.  I've left this running overnight before, to no avail.  My CPU and SSD usage are often pinned to nearly 100% while this is running, and python is currently using 8GB of RAM, so there is definitely something wrong here.

Anaconda has been slow for a while and I've just dealt with it, but it's now clear that there is something seriously wrong.  Do you have any tips for how to fix this or should I jump ship to something like miniconda (will that even make a difference)? -- edit: I was thinking of mamba, not miniconda.

I've tried a couple of the solutions mentioned before, such as removing and re-adding the conda-forge channel.  It doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: Try to reinstall conda like @Jena said in her comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830307/conda-remove-all-installed-packages-from-base-root-environment#comment123587466_52830307

Comment: You can use `micromamba` as a standalone tool to “operate” on Conda installations. Some directions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563455/570918. Also, you may want to check your shell initialization file (e.g., `.bashrc`) for again code pointing to this new environment. Otherwise, yes an Anaconda base struggles if `conda-forge` is added as a channel.