# Activate conda environment without conda

Tags: python, conda

Suppose I have a conda environment folder but no conda nor requirements file. Is there a way to use the environment, i.e. to activate or extract requirements, without installing conda?

Comment: Better to ask it in "is it possible to recover conda env after uninstalling anaconda?" way i guess.

Comment: Thanks @Shayan, I edited the question to be the way I intended -- i.e. a bit more general than env recovery.

Comment: In principle, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51293330/9056440) seems a way to export requirements using the environment's pip. Recreating a new environment from the requirements, however, failed for me ('Invalid URL given'). Either the failure is irrelevant here and in principle it should work or there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Basic Pip exporting

Let's assume the environment is `/path/to/env`, with a `/path/to/env/bin/python` installed. If one only wants the Python packages, and `pip` is installed, then probably sufficient to do:

```bash
/path/to/env/bin/python -s -m pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Note the `-s` flag insulates the `site` module from include packages in a user site (e.g., `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/`); if you want those included for some reason, then drop the flag.

#### Mimicking Conda activation

More diligently, one could simulate a basic activation by

1. Prepending environment's `bin/` to PATH; and
2. Running any activation shell scripts (found in `etc/conda/activate.d/`); note that sometimes there are no such scripts and that folder doesn't exist.

Then exporting could be done with `python -s -m pip list --format=freeze`.

In most cases, I wouldn't expect a difference here, but I include it for completeness. We can't rule out that a package might be out there that manipulates environment variables via activation scripts in such a way that  `pip list` output is changed. Not saying I've seen this, only that it's possible.