# conda export is not saving any dependencies

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to save my conda environment so I can send it to others to reproduce my work. Within my activated environment:

```
(env_name) c:\eric\ conda env export > environment.yml
```

This environment has dozens of packages installed (including `numpy`, `matplotlib`). When I open the resulting `environment.yml` file, I get only:

```
name: env_name
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
prefix: C:\Users\eric\Miniconda3\envs\env_name\envs\env_name
```

That is the **entire** file: there isn't even a line for `dependencies:`  that shows up, which usually does show up for the packages in the env.

I am using miniconda, version `4.12.0`, and have run `conda update conda`.

### Conda issues

I found two issues at conda that have come up with this:

- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8839
- https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10997

One solution at the first issue is to use the following command:

`conda env export -p path-to-folder > environment.yml`

Unfortunately this did not work for me, but it seems to have worked for many.

### Comparison to related question

Note indeed the `prefix` value is pretty strange it typically is something like:

```
C:\Users\eric\.conda\envs\env_name
```

Frankly I am not concerned about that, unlike the related question focused on removing that `prefix` and the accepted answer does that bash shell commands: [Anaconda export Environment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274007/anaconda-export-environment-file).

My question is more first-order: why aren't dependencies showing up in my yaml file?

e.g., something like the following should be appearing:

```
dependencies:
  - pandas=1.0.3=py37h47e9c7a_0
  - qt=5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
  - pip:
    - imageio==2.9.0
    - scikit-image==0.17.2
```

But literally there are *zero* dependencies, and not even a dependencies argument.

Comment: Could you please add some extra debugging info? First, rather than relying on activation, use `conda env export -n env_name`; second, show `conda list -n env_name`; third, with environment activated, show `conda info`.

Comment: `env export -n env_name > environment.yml` worked!!! If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it, but I have no idea why that worked....Interestingly the prefix also changed when I did that....Hmm. It changed to `prefix: C:\Users\Eric\Miniconda3\envs\env_name`

Comment: Done. Yeah, sounds like no environments were activated despite the PS1 indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible the environment isn't properly activated and therefore it's not actually exporting what is wanted. Fortunately, most Conda commands provide arguments to specify an environment explicitly. Specifically, try using the `--name,-n` argument, like

```bash
conda env export -n env_name > env_name.yaml
```

Personally, I try to always use an `--name,-n` or `--prefix,-p` flag, because I find context-sensitive commands are more prone to errors (e.g., installing in incorrect environments).